# Sitecore Workflow - Setting Priority

Tags: workflow

Can we set the priority (i.e. URGENT / NORMAL) for the approval? The high priority workflows are required to be approved first.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be to have 1 workflow with two different paths - Urgent and Normal. 
Content approvers would check in their Workboxes and take Urgent workflow steps prioritized:

[image]

Workflow would look similarly to this one:

[image]

I have seen your previous question here on SSE with lot of other questions regarding workflow and wrote this blog post about the same with more details. You can find it here -> http://tothecore.sk/2018/04/06/sitecore-workflows-adding-new-states-commands-and-actions

Comment: Thanks Peter but if we have to change the priority from normal to urgent after sometime then I dont that will be possible in this solution?

Comment: There's nothing to stop you adding an additional path, so you can move from normal to urgent. You could even write a scheduled task to move them automatically after a certain amount of time.

Comment: I 100% agree with @jammykam.